# How to add field to Object that may not yet exist?

Tags: javascript

I have a `this._champ` object (which is undefined by default).

I browser an array, and want to add this field with a value : `this._champ[champ.name][ele.infos[0].StackableRangeName] = ele.value;` but at the first iteration, [champ.name] is `undefined`, and `[ele.infos[0].StackableRangeName]` is always `undefined`, how to manage this?

I tried this ternary operator but it isn't working:

```
      this.champ[champ.name] != undefined ? this._champ[champ.name].push({ele.infos[0].StackableRangeName: ele.value}) : this._champ.push({champ.name: {ele.infos[0].StackableRangeName: ele.value}})
```

Comment: If it doesnt exist you cant add anything to it. You either need to ensure that it exists and THEN add something to it or store the data you need somewhere else and set it after the object is created.

Comment: That's a shame we can't manage this in other way :(

Comment: Why a shame? In any language, you must tell that your object is an array before pushing elements. That's common sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common idiom for initializing something with a default value if it's not yet set:

```
this.champ[champ.name] = this.champ[champ.name] || []
```

Comment: Thanks you, that's exacly what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

Just check for existence of the key. and then push value:

```
if(this.champ && !this.champ.hasOwnProperty(champ.name)) {
     this.champ[champ.name] = [];
}
this._champ[champ.name].push({ele.infos[0].StackableRangeName: ele.value});
```